# Unique factorization domain and principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

> If R was a unique factorization domain, can we deduce that for a nonzero element d in R, d has a finite number of divisors?

I need this in solving this question
 "If R is a unique factorization domain then there are only finite number of distinct principal ideals that contain the ideal (d)."

My idea to solve it: if a divides d then (d) is contained in (a), so if we have finite divisors then we have finite principal ideals.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Your idea is basically good. Note, however, that there might be infinitely many *units* in the domain, and those divide every element.

Comment: @Berci but since it is a unique factorization domain if there is infinitly many divisors then they must be associate.

Comment: Yes, of course, but there would be effectively infinitely many divisors. If we quotient out by 'being associate' then we arrive to the principal ideals, as $(a)=(b)\ \iff\ a\sim b$.

Comment: @Berci Yes being associate means that there ideals are equal. 
Doesn't this leads that they are finite?

Comment: The point is that the number of divisors, that is, elements of the ring dividing $d$, need not be finite. But the number of classes of associated divisors is finite, and that is the number of principal ideals containing $(d)$. You must distinguish between these things. If you do, your idea works out.

Comment: @DanielFischer okay, so we have an infinite number of divisors that have a finite number of classes ( being associate) i.e a finite number of principal ideals , which completes the solution.
Thank u the idea is clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

*(This is a CW answer to get this question out of the unanswered queue.)*

---

Yes, the ideas are basically right.

The divisors of $d$ (up to associates) determine the principal ideals containing $(d)$ in the way you describe. The fact that $d$ has a unique set of irreducibles that it factors into limits the number of containing principal ideals to finitely many (corresponding to divisors determined by those irreducibles.)