# Principal ideal domain with finitely many ideals

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

Let $aR$ be a nonzero ideal in a PID $R$. Show that $R/aR$ is a ring with only finitely many ideals.

Honestly, I do not know how to start. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: Here's [the same problem rephrased for UFDs](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/640403/29335). Maybe not a dupe, but definitely a generalized-dupe.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ By the [correspondence theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39370/242) ideals in $R/aR$ are in bijection with ideals $\,bR\,$ in $R$ that contain $\,aR.\ $ But $\,bR\supseteq aR\,$ iff $\, b\mid a,\,$ since contains = divides for principal ideals. Hence the problem reduces to the finitness of the number of divisors (up to associateness), which is immediate if you know that PIDs are UFDs.

Comment: R/aR = set of cosets of aR, right? and bR is an ideal in R, how to see bR relates to R/aR?

Comment: @user222262 The relation is given by the correspondence theorem - see the answers given in the linked question.

Comment: That shows a = bm and it is finitely factors. In other words, it relates to aR only, right? I can't see the link between the number of elements of aR and the number of ideals of R/aR.

Comment: @user222262  There are only finitely many ideals in $\,R/aR\,$ because they are in bijection with the finite set of ideals $\,bR\supseteq aR\,$ in $\,R,\,$ i.e. the factors $\,b\,$ of $\,a\,$ in the UFD $\,R\,$ (up to associateness, i.e. ignoring unit factors)

Comment: Thanks for being patient to me. I think I got it. :)

Comment: @user222262 Great!