# Principal Ideal Domain $R$ and ideal $J\neq 0$ so that that $R/J$ have a finite number of ideals.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ a un Principal Ideal Domain(PID) and $J\neq 0$ a ideal of $R$. Show that $R/J$ have a finite number of ideals.

Comment: No effort duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/640403/29335. Unfortunately, those helping that poster only made comments and no solutions. I left a CW answer to rectify the situation. If someone upvotes that then this can be closed as a dupe of that one.

Comment: Never mind, found a closer duplicate with an answer. Please use the search feature next time.

Answer (score 1):

By CRT, it is enough to prove that $R/(f^n)$, for an irreducible element $f$ and $n$ a natural number, has a finite number of ideals. But the ideals in this ring are in bijection with the ideals of $R$ which contain the ideal $(f^n)$.