# Why $R/J$ has finite ideals if $R$ PID?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I have this problem:

> Let $R$ a PID and $J\subseteq R$ a non-zero ideal. Prove that $R/J$ has a finite number of ideals.

I think that I must use the biyective correspondance between the ideals of $R$ that contain $J$ and the ideals of $R/J$, but I still don't see why I have a finite number of ideals that contain $J$. Can anyone give me a hint or I'm going in the wrong way?

Comment: Also see the questions linked to the duplicate for more help. Also please search for your question before you post: you could find all of these just by searching for "PID finitely many ideals" and so on.

Comment: I tried to avoid duplicating a post, but I didn't try with that title to see. Now I see why it has finite divisors.

Comment: If you follow the links between questions, you'll hit [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055846/29335) which clarifies the application of the more general result.

Comment: Does exist any post about integral domains with prime finite ideals? I don't find it as posted before.

Comment: Isn't the link in my previous comment such a post? ([the link again](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055846/29335))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $R$ is a PID, any ideal in $R$ is principal.  Let $J=(x)$ and let $I=(y)$ be another ideal.  Then $J\subseteq I$ if and only if $y$ divides $x$.

Can you show that there are (up to multiplication by units) only finitely many elements of $R$ that divide $x$?

Comment: The PIDs are artinian?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois A domain that is Artinian is a field. So **no**, PIDs are typically not Artinian.

Comment: Sorry, now I see why it has finite divisors. I didn't see that a PID is a UFD too. So the factorization has finite non-unit divisors, implying what you said.